# Why is the path of the image null, after calling the MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

```
File fullPath;
public void mybutton_testfullsize(View v)   {

    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File directory = new File(this.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir("/Data/"), "MyPublicFolder");

    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs();
    }

    File fullPath = new File(directory,   "pic.png");
    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", fullPath);

    takePicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
    startActivityForResult(takePicture, 2);
}
```

I am using the above method to take a photo and save it in the given path. In on ActivityResult I want to use the variable fullPath, but it is always null.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch (requestCode) {
         case 2:   if(fullPath.exists()){...}}
```

fullPath.exists() gives always an NullpointerException. How can I access the path? I don't want to hardcode it, because I want to implement an app, where the path changes.

Comment: There is no `mypath` in your first code snippet. Make sure that you are retaining your path value in the saved instance state `Bundle`, as your app's process may be terminated while the camera app is in the foreground. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/Camera/FileProvider) is a bit old but it shows the basic steps for taking a picture using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and `FileProvider`.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I mean fullPath, I have corrected it. I have just edited it in StackOverflow, because the actual name was to long. The problem is that I can't use Bundle, because the intent in onActivityResult is null, when using putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI).

Comment: Sorry, but that is not the `Bundle` that I am referring to. I am referring to the saved instance state `Bundle`, supplied to you in `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#saras).

Comment: `File fullPath = new File(directory,...` make that `fullPath = new File(directory,...`. Otherwise you create a local variable instead of using the first one.

Comment: @blackapps thank you very much! This solved the problem!